# connect two data extensions without a common PK

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

Every Customer has a CustomerID, sku, userID and sessionID
I have two data extensions that I want to join so the CustomerID links with the sku, userID and sessionID

First (table name)
sku(pk)
userID
sessionID

Second 
CustomerID(pk)

Is there any way I can join this two?

Comment: is there a common element outside the PKs? A sort of foreign key?  Without a mapping of fields, there is nothing to connect dataset A to dataset B. So on second, is there a sku, userId or session id?  Or some other shared field that is not listed

Comment: I have another data extension with a sku. The problem is, when I join the sku from the first table with the sku from the other table I only get the records of one sku if that makes sense

Comment: It sounds like you need to do some data modeling based on the relationships in order to correctly combine these into a single table. Without access to how your data is modeled, it is hard for us to advise how to do it